# import date pattern data and ignore other strings in java

Tags: java, oracle, date, insert

I am fetching data from file using filestream and importing this data into oracle tables. I have column '`FT__FIRST`' which is `Date` data type in oracle table and where i only need date values to be inserted and ignore other values. From file the date is coming in format '`YYYYMMDD`'. In future if there is other values coming from file rather than `Date` datatype for this column and if it tries to insert into oracle table then the java code might throw an error as literal string does not match.

So to avoid this issue i want to modify my java code such that it can take only insert date format value and ignore other values. Currently i am handling only specific string from file which i know and ignoring it as they are not date format..

Java uses classes DateTimeformatter but dont know how to use it in my code..

```
private String createUpdateTableSql(String line, String tableName, String dateFormat, List<ColumnData> columnData) {
        List<String> data = Splitter.on("|").trimResults().splitToList(line);
        String ftFirst = "";
        String tr = "";
        String pds = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < columnData.size(); i++) {
            if(columnData.get(i) == null || "N.A.".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i)) || "N.A".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i)) || "UNKNOWN".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i))) {
                continue;
            }

            if ("FT_FIRST".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                ftFirst = data.get(i);
            }

            if ("TR".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                tr = data.get(i);
            }

            if ("P_S_SOURCE".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                pds = data.get(i);
            }                                

        }

        return "UPDATE " + tableName + " " + 
               "SET FT_FIRST=to_date('" + ftFirst + "','YYYYMMDD')" +
               " WHERE TR='" + ticker + 
               "' AND P_S_SOURCE='" + pds + "'";   
    }
```

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate values into your SQL string. [Use a `PreparedStatement`](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface) - for security and performance reasons. Date values should be passed as instances of `java.sql.Date` or even better as `java.time.LocalDate` not as strings

Comment: but actually there has to be no issue till now regarding performance and security

Comment: sure i will check the documentation ..do u also have idea how we can make use of datetimeformatter or any other suggestion just to check Date here and ignore other values ?

Answer (score 0):

When you read data from file, you could parse the date field to date object like below:

```
// NEW CODE
private Date getDateValue(String sDate, String format) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    try {
        return
                sdf.parse(format);
    } catch (ParseException ignored) {
        // TODO: Log this exception return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are parsing a string to date with an expected format `yyyyMMdd` (YYYYMMDD on oracle)

If parsing fails (value field does not containts the expected format) you can add the logic as you want on catch clausule or ignore error and let value as null.

Your code will be like this:

```
private String createUpdateTableSql(String line, String tableName, String dateFormat, List<ColumnData> columnData) {
        List<String> data = Splitter.on("|").trimResults().splitToList(line);
        String futNoticeFirst = "";
        String ticker = "";
        String pds = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < columnData.size(); i++) {
            if (columnData.get(i) == null || "N.A.".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i)) || "N.A".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i)) || "UNKNOWN".equalsIgnoreCase(data.get(i))) {
                continue;
            }

            if ("FUT_NOTICE_FIRST".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                futNoticeFirst = getDateValue(data.get(i), 'yyyyMMdd');
            }

            if ("TICKER".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                ticker = data.get(i);
            }

            if ("PARSEKYABLE_DES_SOURCE".equalsIgnoreCase(columnData.get(i).getName().trim())) {
                pds = data.get(i);
            }

        }

        return "UPDATE " + tableName + " " +
                "SET FUT_NOTICE_FIRST= " + futNoticeFirst +
        " WHERE TICKER='" + ticker +
                "' AND PARSEKYABLE_DES_SOURCE='" + pds + "'";
    }

    // NEW CODE
    private Date getDateValue(String sDate, String format) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            return
                    sdf.parse(format);
        } catch (ParseException ignored) {
            // TODO: Log this exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you please update the suggested changes that i need to do in my method to handle this...i am quiet new to filestream handling so dont know how to handle data correctly from file so has to insert in oracle table

Comment: I updated the suggesed changes on your code. When it will be review, you will see it modified

Comment: Please don't edit questions with a proposed solution. Instead, [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57285953/edit), copying the relevant code from the question and apply the changes in there. Otherwise it will be confusing to future readers what the problem was with the original code.

Comment: Please don't teach the young ones to use the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class and the equally outdated `Date`. Today we have so much better in java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The classes we need are `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: @OleV.V. can you please tell me how do you use the same API and make changes in my existing method ?

Comment: @JaumeMoróniTarrasa i am getting error while trying the above code...futNoticeFirst data type should be changed i guess and also at this line futNoticeFirst = getDateValue(data.get(i), 'yyyyMMdd');

Comment: Sorry, you will have to do with [a link to the Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for now.

Comment: @OleV.V. so u came back for vacation ;) i tried to do with tutorial currently i just tried to check data pattern and ignoring the other corrupt values but still i dont got idea how to check date only and then ignore other values :(